# Erro ao tentar usar JavaFX 11 com Netbeans 9.0

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, java-11

Estou tentando atualizar minha versão do `Java` para a 11, porém não consigo fazer funcionar na `IDE`.

Esse erro aparece ao tentar criar um novo projeto.

Sei que o `JavaFX` foi retirado do `JDK` a partir da versão 11, e que deve ser acrescentando como uma biblioteca no projeto, mas a `IDE` não permite nem a criação de um novo projeto exibindo esse erro.

Não encontrei nada parecido no Google, provavelmente é algum processo que estou fazendo errado.

Como resolver?

> **Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.**
>   Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime.
>   Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website

[Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9F4w.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

O Java 11 não vem mais com o JavaFX embutido. A partir do Java 11, o JavaFX 11 deve ser baixado separadamente [aqui](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Se você estiver usando o Maven, pode colocar isso no seu `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
    <version>12-ea+7</version>
</dependency>
```

Se estiver usando Gradle, você declara a dependência assim:

```
compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: '12-ea+7'
```

Conforme descrito [aqui](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans), no NetBeans 9.0, você pode escolher o menu <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Libraries</kbd>. Na tela que se abrir, clicar no botão <kbd>New Library...</kbd>, dar o nome da biblioteca de `JavaFX` e então, adicionar nessa biblioteca os JARs necessários.

Pelo menos para mim, o NetBeans não reconhece os JMODs, então para montar a biblioteca no NetBeans você pode precisar ter que desmontar os JMODs e reempacotá-los em JARs para o NetBeans aceitá-los.

Uma vez que a biblioteca esteja criada no NetBeans, você pode adicioná-la a projetos novos ou a projetos já existentes.

Ao criar um novo projeto com JavaFX no NetBeans, não escolha um novo projeto JavaFX. Ao invés disso, use um novo projeto Java e adicione o JavaFX. O motivo disso é que os scripts ANT gerados pelo NetBeans 9.0 não são compatíveis com o JavaFX 11.

Houve vários motivos pelo qual o JavaFX foi retirado de dentro da JDK para viver separadamente:

- A Oracle não tem mais interesse em desenvolver o JavaFX. No entanto, outros grupos de desenvolvedores têm. Assim, fazia sentido que o JavaFX saísse da possessão da Oracle.
- Os esforços a partir do Java 8 são de reduzir o tamanho da JDK e aumentar a sua modularização (culminando com os módulos do Java 9). Para atingir esse objetivo, fazia-se necessário que o JavaFX vivesse fora da JDK.
- É interessante para os dois lados que os releases do JavaFX sejam independentes dos releases da JDK. Acoplar obrigatoriamente os releases de um ao outro era considerado uma desvantagem. Inclusive, você pode ver as versões do JavaFX [aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base).

Assim sendo, a decisão tomada no início de 2018 seria a de que o JavaFX seria retirado de dentro da JDK. Não havia mais tempo para retirá-lo de dentro do Java 10 que seria em breve lançado, então decidiram que o Java 10 ainda o incluiria, mas seria a última versão a fazê-lo. Dessa forma, o Java 11 é a primeira versão que não o inclui mais.